# How to pass arguments in a script using gnome-terminal

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, sudo, scripts

As part of a script I have

```
gnome-terminal -e "process involving another user"
```

Once executed this line, I have to write in the terminal 3 times the password of this user. I wonder how can I automate it, that is, without typing the password. Something as

```
echo "password" (3 times) | gnome-terminal -e "process involving another user"
```

Thank @rao_555, but I'm afraid things are not so easy. I use the command

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="/var/singlecellserver/single-cell-server" \
    -e "sage -python trusted_db.py -w 50 --untrusted-account untrusted@localhost" &
```

So, I don't want pass arguments to `sage -python ...`. Once `sage -python ...` is launched I need to give 3 times untrusted's password. I tried

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="/var/singlecellserver/single-cell-server" \
    -x sage -python trusted_db.py -w 50 --untrusted-account untrusted@localhost $1 $1 $1 &
```

but no success.

#### SOLVED

The problem was related to `sudo` and `ssh`. Since it is necessary to launch the process as `su`, the access via `ssh` to the untrusted account needs the `ssh` keys also in the root folder.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

make a shell script and put your commands inside it, pass the password only once as argument, and inside the script use $1 to get your password,

use $1 to get your password wherever you want inside your script.

Comment: Thank you, rao_555, but I'm afraid things are not so easy. The command I use is

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect`

See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065

Should be straight forward enough, post if you need assistance.